# Data getting duplicated in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model , if I send request with the same name the data is getting created and not giving any errors of duplicity
mongoose version is 8.1.1
express version is 4.18.2 and MongoDb version is 6.0.13
Please help me

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

 const listingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name : {type : String, required : true,  unique: true},
    description : {type : String, required : true},
    email :{type : String, required : false},
    type : {type : String, required : true},
    service : {type : Boolean, required : true},
    available : {type : Boolean, required : true}

 })

 export const Listing = mongoose.model("Listing", listingSchema)`
```

I have tried some things from internet like dropping the collection and then hitting the API again but still hasn't worked

Comment: Can you check if a unique index was created on your collection? Using mongosh you can run `db.listings.getIndexes()` or in compass you can select the Indexes tab.

Comment: Yes the name index was not there with unique property, I have created it now using shell and is working fine now but do I have to do this everytime ?

Comment: It may be that you already had 2 documents with the same name in the collection then you added `unique: true` so an index could not be created. If you can, best to drop the collection and restart your server.